# how can let two windows(a window is opened by another) communicate

Tags: javascript

if the title is not clear 
let me describe it again
if has a page a.html that has a javascript code below

```
    window.open("http://www.baidu.com/", "_self", "");
```

and how can the original window and the new opened window  communicate??

thanks

Comment: a quick google will be faster. i've seen this one a lot.

Comment: @Joseph you mean google is fast than baidu??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new document will have an `opener` property that references the window from which it was opened. This will be lost if the browser is navigated to a new document.

The *return value* of `open` will be a reference to the new window (so you'll need to assign it to a variable).

The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) applies as usual.

Comment: by testing,the attribute openner of that opened by "_self" is null.

Comment: Your question is self-contradictory. The title asks about two windows communicating, the code reuses the existing window. Two windows can't communicate if there aren't two windows.

Comment: oh yes  my expression is not vary exact

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are on the same domain AND you actually open a NEW window ("_self" is not a great idea to open a NEW window) you can do

`var w = window.open(....)`

`w.document....`

and from child window

`opener.someFunction()`

or

`opener.someVar = ...`

If they are not, you need cross domain scripting

Comment: Ah, did not notice the _self. That will then not open a new window if the browser allows the code